# Nothing loaded after shortcode Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I got a very very strange bug! Im making a Wordpress blog theme and im fine but now i am making some posts, i wanted to insert HTML so i used some plugins so im able to add snippets to my post. Actually after i insert a shortcode all my HTML thats behind that shortcode doesnt get loaded! Here is an example:

[image: http://g2f.nl/00ly99l]

As you see my page is completely blank after the content, so my menu etc is loading but my sidebar isn't i tried multiple plugins but it seems to do this with all shortcodes. Does someone now what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'r probably missing a closing tag somewhere.

Comment: @JonasCz Can't without shortcodes my website runs perfect!

Comment: Can you please post some the HTML you're trying to insert in your Wordpress blog?

Comment: @mjuarez i just want to insert some random HTML code as an snippet into my post. Im using the Post Snippets plugin. But with ALL shortcodes i get this also with other plugins :/

Comment: Check your webserver error log, your site probably crashes after it does the shortcode.